# How to use custom metadata in validation rule?

Tags: apex, validation, validation-rule, custom-metadata

How to use a custom metadata records checkbox field in validation rule over a custom Object? 
Is there any way?

Comment: Have you even tried googling this? First hit I get: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring18/release-notes/rn_forcecom_development_custom_metadata_validation_rule_formula.htm

Comment: @RobinDeBondt You might consider adding that as an answer.

Comment: Yes i tried the same.. But i cant refer it. The field i am trying to refer from custom metadata says does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

This is [GA since the Summer '18 release](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_forcecom_development_custom_metadata_types.htm).

Comment: Yes my org is in Summer 18th Release Version

Comment: My Custom Metadata is also set to public. Don't know why its not working.